# Get a numpy ndarray (view, not copy) from a double pointer (from CythonGSL)

Tags: python, numpy, cython

While using CythonGSL, I find myself needing to create a numpy.ndarray view to a "gsl vector," which is defined in the following cython code:

```
ctypedef struct gsl_vector:
    size_t size
    size_t stride
    double *data
    gsl_block *block
    int owner
```

So I can access the size of the vector as well as the pointer to it. How can I use these to get a numpy.ndarray view to this vector?

Here is my failed attempt:

```
import numpy as np
cdef mycast(const gsl_vector *v):
    cdef size_t n = v.size
    return np.ctypeslib.as_array((ctypes.c_double * n).from_address(v.data))
```

However, this fails with

```
Cannot convert 'const double *' to Python object
```

What is the correct way to do the casting?

Comment: I'm not sure why what you tried didn't work, but another option is to use the  numpy `__array_interface__`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html#arrays-interface  The basic idea is to define a python object with an `__array_interface__` method that returns a dict with the shape, dtype, and memory address of the data. Numpy can then use that to create a view of the data from the python side.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one thing that works:

```
import numpy as np
from cython cimport view
cdef mycast(const gsl_vector *v):
    cdef size_t n = v.size
    cdef double[:] myview = <double[:n]> v.data
    return np.asarray(myview)
```

Reading through the [cython typed memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) doc was helpful, but I would still appreciate some answers about what the best practices (both for efficiency as well as for continued correctness) here are.